# Django & Docker : manage dependencies between production & dev environment

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am softly switching from using virtual machine to docker. I'm starting with my dev environment.

I was used to have my setting file split between a `base.py` and a `dev.py` and `prod.py`. The `prod.py` has some apps I don't need during the development such  as newrelic / error trackers and `DEBUG=False`.

How do you manage this with docker ? You build multiples images with the different settings ? Or is there a better solution to manage this ?

Here is the `docker-compose.yml` file I use:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'user'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'name'
  web:
    build: ./project
    image: project
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000 --reload
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control all the behavior of your application with environment variables from the host machine taking advantage of the [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) feature of docker compose. For example the POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD can be define as enviroment variables in you dev machine and in your deployment machine with different values. 
Also you can have two different build images defined and using each one depending on env variable

```
build: ./project-${HOST}
```

and in `project-dev` have a Dockerfile with dev dependencies and in `project-deploy` another Dockerfile.